# Find the area bounded with the curve $x=1+t-t^3, \ \ y=1-15t^2.$

Tags: definite-integrals, area, parametric

> Find the area bounded with the curve $$x=1+t-t^3, \ \ y=1-15t^2.$$

I drew its graph and looks like this:

[image]

It seems to be symmetric about $x=1$. So, the idea that came to me was to cut by half and study any of the pieces. However, I don't know how... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you figured out what is the range of $t$ covering that loop? Many ways to calculate the area. Have you covered how areas can be calculated using Green's theorem? If not, then you can cover it with either vertical strips with area $y\,dx$ or horizontal strips with are $x\,dy$, and integrate over the prescribed range of $t$ to add them up.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It seems I don't know this theorem

Comment: Then what examples about calculating the area bounded by a parametrized curve have you seen? BTW, the parametrization and the picture don't match. The same value of $x$ is achieved with three values of $t$ in the picture, and that is surely impossible. Are you sure $x$ is not supposed to be cubic?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In the examples before, it was quite possible to express $y$ in terms of $x$. Yes, you are right, that was a typo in the power of $t$.

Comment: Did you figure out the range of $t$ covering, say, the right half of the loop? You should practice that before you can start thinking about calculating the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $1+t-t^3=1+u-u^3,\,1-15t^2=1-15u^2,\,t\ne u$ then$$t\ne0,\,u=-t,\,1+t-t^3=1-t+t^3\implies 2t(1-t^2)=0\implies t=\pm1.$$So the area is from $t=-1$ to $t=1$. As $t$ increases from $-1$ to $0$, we trace out the left-hand part of the area's circumference; from $t=0$ to $t=1$, we follow the right-hand part. The shape vertically stretches from $t=\pm1,\,y=-14$ to $t=0,\,y=1$. From $y$ to $y+dy=y-30tdt$, a strip exists of width $2t(1-t^2)$, so the area is$$\int_0^160t^2(1-t^2)dt=60\int_0^1(t^2-t^4)dt=8.$$As a sanity check, the area fits in a rectangle of height $15$ and width $4/(3\sqrt{3})$ (because $x$ is extremised at $t=\pm1/\sqrt{3},\,x=1\mp2/(3\sqrt{3})$), so of area $20/\sqrt{3}>8$.

Comment: when you start integrating you seem to multiply $2t(1-t^2)$ by $30tdt$... why is that?

Comment: @VIVID The area element is $|xdy|$.

Answer (score -1):

Cut the curve into left and right values for $x$ at each $y$ and make use of the symmetry.
$$ {{\int_{-14}^{1} x_r-x_\ell\,\mathrm d y }={2\int_0^1 (x(t)-1)\,\left\lvert\frac{\mathrm d y(t)}{\mathrm d t}\right\rvert\,\mathrm  d t}}$$